# Instanceof 'Class' return false using a mock object

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I'm testing a method and I need to use a mock object as parameter (I am using [typemoq](https://github.com/florinn/typemoq)). The problem is that the instanceof check, always return false. How can I solve?

```js
public foo(container: BaseClass): string {
    if (container instanceof Application) { // Always returns false when I use a mock of the object
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
    return retval;
  }
```

In my spec.ts

```js
context('foo', () => {
  it('should return...', () => {
    const container = Mock.ofType<Application>();
    const result = class.foo(container.object);
  });
});
```

I tried this too, but the result is the same.

```js
context('foo', () => {
  it('should return...', () => {
    const application = new Application();
    const container = Mock.ofInstance(application);
    const result = class.foo(container.object);
  });
});
```

How can I fix this? I need to test what append when the parameter is an instance of 'Application'.
Thank you.

Comment: Just pass `application` in the second attempt?

Comment: I can't, because in the test I mock a method of application. That's why I am using a mock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Just change .object in .target in the tests.

```js
context('foo', () => {
  it('should return...', () => {
    const application = new Application();
    const container = Mock.ofInstance(application);
    const result = class.foo(container.target); // instead of .object
  });
});
```

In this way it is possible to mock the methods of 'Application' class and the 'instanceof Class' will return true